# How to use Faker-variables in a pre-request-script in Postman?

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

PostMan supports faker-library and provides several variables like "randomFirstName" and so on. However, I try to make them work in a pre-request script.

I've found a [blogpost](https://howdoitestthat.com/postman-faker) about this topic telling that it actually should work:

```
pm.variables.replaceIn("{{$randomProductName}}")
```

However, for me it doesn't work. The variable won't be replaced:

```
var firstName = "{{$randomFirstName}}"

console.log(firstName)
```

The output is:

> {{$randomFirstName}}

How can I use these variables in a pre-request-script in PostMan?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use the `{{}}` syntax in the pre-request and test tabs.

The following will do:

```
var firstName = pm.variables.replaceIn("{{$randomFirstName}}");
```